# SQL Server service not starting automatically on Windows Server 2008 express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

My websites are running on virtual Windows server 2008 R2 Standard. The server had an unplanned reboot. The SQL Server 2008 Express instance service **Startup Type** is automatic but the service did not start upon reboot and I had to manually restart the service.

Any ideas why it won't start up automatically? Can we setup some sort of alert in SQL Server when this service is down?

Comment: There is a lot of reasons why a service don't start up. Have you checked the event log to see if the service tried to start up?